# Method may fail to close stream on exception

Tags: java, stream, findbugs

I get a critical error with findbugs:

> The method creates an IO stream object, does not assign it to any fields, pass it to other methods, or return it, and does not appear to close it on all possible exception paths out of the method.  This may result in a file descriptor leak.  It is generally a good idea to use a finally block to ensure that streams are closed.

```
try {
...
stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
...
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    try {
        if (stdError != null) {
            stdError.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Do I need to close `InputStreamReader` also or `p.getErrorStream` (it returns `InputStream`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BufferedReader and InputStreamReader both close the underlying stream when they are closed. You should be fine by closing `stdError`

Answer (score 5):

What happens when an exception is thrown while creating the `BufferedReader` object?  The stream managed by the `InputStreamReader` object is not closed until some time in the future when the garbage collector decides to destroy the object.

You will likely have similar problems if an exception is thrown while creating the `InputStreamReader` object.

Comment: You and findbugs are technically correct.  However, the only way that that BufferedReader constructor can fail is with an `Error`; e.g. OOME or SOE.  An application is unlikely to try recover from one of those, so the leak of the stream is unlikely to matter.